# If $n^s\in \mathbb{N}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, must $s\in\mathbb{N}?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

My friend and I were discussing this, and while it looks obviously true, weren't very successful in getting anywhere with it. I'm not sure whether I lack the tools to solve this or whether I am missing something obvious. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try proving the contrapositive.

Comment: This was a Putnam 1971 problem. Here is a solution: https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol716.html (Posting as a comment as the dupe answer mentions putnam 1971)

Answer (score 1):

*Partial solution: if $s$ is not an integer, then it has to be transcendental.*

1. It cannot be a rational number. Otherwise say $s={p\over q}$ with $q>1,\gcd(p,q)=1$, and $N=2^s\in\Bbb N$ $$q\ |\ v_2(N^q)=v_2(2^{p})=p$$
   which contradicts $q>1,\gcd(p,q)=1$. Here $v_2$ stands for the [$2$-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) function.
2. Now since $s$ is not a rational, it follows from [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) that it cannot be an algebraic number either. Otherwise $2^s$ would be transcendental.

One can observe that so far only the fact that $2^s\in\Bbb N$ has been used. This condition alone is not sufficient to rule out transcendental numbers as was pointed out by Grant B., e.g. $2^{\log_2(3)}=3$.

Comment: $2^s\in\mathbb{N}$ is not sufficient, as $s=\log_2(3)$ is a counterexample. However, $2^s\in\mathbb{N}$ and $3^s\in\mathbb{N}$ together should be sufficient.

Comment: @GrantB. Thanks. Included.